# Button_to with text and image rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, button-to

How to create a button with label and image in Rails3?

This code only show an image:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("newRevision.png"), {:controller => :review_transitions, :action => :show_step}, {:class => "navBtn"} %>
```

but... the image with text?

```
<%= link_to "example_text"+image_tag("newRevision.png"), {:controller => :review_transitions, :action => :show_step}, {:class => "navBtn"} %>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be something along these lines

```
<%= link_to image_tag('image/someimage.png') + "Some text", some_path) %>
```

Comment: thanks Richlewis for your answer... but I want the image behind the text... "Some text" + image_tag... is posible?¿